# Reduce execution time of Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, performance, stored-procedures

I have a db job running daily that manages to process 10.000 rows from a table of 3.500.000 rows, in three hours.
Tuning the main cursor's select statement can only save me 30 minutes, but I need to reduce the job running time from 3 hours to 10-15 minutes.
I have to state that there is only the main loop for the cursor and for each record there are calls to external systems, in order to get or send data, so this is an overhead I cannot control. The time for each record to be processed after it is fetched is a little less than a second and that is not acceptable ...

Is there something I could do? All ideas are more than welcome!

Comment: Did you tried explaining your query? what Index? which table? What schema? How busy is your dataserver? Are there any memory constraints etc?

Comment: Try to run your procedure WITHOUT calling external systems, How long does it take? Problem is probably not in cursor, but in external systems. What do you mean with "calls to external systems"?

Comment: The queries I use are tuned and I have the correct indexes in use.
The external systems are used for validation of data (public registries, etc) and retrieving additional information according e.g to the SSN.
What I am asking is if there could be a way to process the next rows while waiting for the external systems (which creates the huge overhead) to respond about the previous rows. There is setup in the production environment to allow me run in parallel so I'm trying to find a way to cheat ...

Answer (score 0):

Imho, you can submit job for each query to external system or try to run in parallel, may be you can use ADVANSED QUEUE. Explain: send each selected row to queue, and quering to external will proceed with AQ

Answer (score -1):

You may try to process rows in parallel.